# Connectedness of the Given Set

Tags: general-topology

How will I find out that $A=\{(x,y) \in\Bbb C^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ is connected or not in $\Bbb C^2$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we have the usual rational parametrization of the conic $C=\{-z_0^2+z_1^2+z_2^2=0\}\subset\mathbb CP^2$:
$$f\colon \mathbb CP^1\to\mathbb CP^2, \quad f([t_0,t_1]) = [t_0^2+t_1^2,2t_0t_1,t_0^2-t_1^2]\,.$$
The points $[1,\pm i]$ map to the two points at infinity, and so $A\subset C$ is parametrized by $\mathbb CP^1 - \{\text{two points}\} \cong \mathbb C-\{0\}$, which is connected.

In affine coordinates, we're mapping $t\in\mathbb C-\{\pm i\}$ to $\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)$, and the point $\infty\in\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ maps to $(0,1)$. This map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Bah, almost did it but you posted it first...:) +1 . Anyway, I was trying to avoid projective space stuff...

Comment: Presumably we can make a linear fractional change of coordinates taking $i$ to $\infty$ and $-i$ to $0$ and then have a nice map from $\mathbb C-\{0\}$ to $A$, but I was too lazy. :P